# Where is the sql so I can see the criteria that hibernate repository uses to filter out records in findById()"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an Oracle table mapped to a Hibernate repository.

In the code I only see

```
public interface MyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTableRacord, Long> {
}
```

Where is the sql that findById(Long id) uses?

*What criteria is it using to filter out the records?*

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ or Eclipse you probably have ability to go inside this JpaRepository class by clicking on it with pressed CTRL. Just try to go up and up and you will probably get your answer.

Comment: I use IntelliJ but for some reason, ctrl-click does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using spring-boot you could change log level in `properties` and get all statement SQL have used for Hibernate

```
# SETTINGS FOR MORE DETAILS ON HIBERNATE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

# CHANGE LEVEL LOG FOR HIBERNATE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

# CHANGE LEVEL LOG FOR SPRING JDBC
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=TRACE

## YOU CAN USE 'INFO' OR 'DEBUG' INSTEAD OF 'TRACE' AS YOU PREFER
```

Comment: Is there any way to see the sql query without actually running it?

Comment: I don't think so you can get statement SQL with no running, because Spring JPA uses JPA specification on SQL and depends on the type of database/driver the SQL can be changed.

Comment: What criteria is it using to filter out the records?

Comment: May your `MyTableRacord.class` has a attribute that contains `@Id` annotation. surely`findById(id)` is filtering where this attr is equals